# Magento Persistent cart cookie is not generated for guests and I want that guest must be able to add items for 24 hrs in cart

Tags: php, ee-1.13.1.0

I am facing problem with persistent shopping cart for guest (Not logged in user),

1. Cookie Lifetime - 31536000 - 365 days // Cookie lifetime
2. Persistence Lifetime (seconds) - 2100000 // Persistent shopping cart lifetime
3. Cookie path - / // Cookie path set to /
4. Cookie Domain - set it to blank // I have kept it blank
5. Session Lifetime (seconds) - 2100000 - 24 hrs // Set session Lifetime for 24 hrs

but it it always expire after 1 hr for guest user(not logged in user). Please tell me the solution. I am getting stuck now.

Thanks to everyone in advance!.

Comment: which version of magento?  you have tagged 3 different versions (not possible)

Comment: Have you checked the PHP values on the server?

Comment: Hello guys I am using magento version 1.13.1.0 and I have not checked PHP values on the server but can't we setup persistent shopping for not logged in user from admin panel?

Why do we need to checked the values on the server please tell me.@PaddyD

Comment: From memory the server php values over rides anything set in magento ie   if the server is set for 1 hr then the max value you can set in magento is 1 hr

Comment: ref this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022952/set-session-time-out-limit-for-magento-frontend